# Twilio convert incoming call to conference by default

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, twilio

i am building a calling application where in twilio i have multiple numbers and when any person calls that one of the numbers i am getting an call in my application i am using nodejs and express in backend and react js in frontend. but i want when someone calls my number i want it to be an conference number by default and i will be able to pick the call, btw i am using twilio client sdk.
the real real reason behind this cause i cant hold my call and if i use ENQUEUE twiml my call gets disconnected and cant unhold that call again. so i thought it would be better if i made the call as conference by default. if there is any other better solutions i would appreciate that.
thank you.
Code Examples would be much apprediated cause i am new to twilio.

CODE LINK: https://github.com/debashis221/calling

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: like i want when an inoming calls comes in twilio i want it to be a conference call. by doing this i think i can hold the participant and mute that and also i will be able to add participant in that call i guess

Answer (score 0):

In your call handler webhook add this code

```
$response = new VoiceResponse;

$dial = $response->dial();
$dial->conference('My conference', array(
        'startConferenceOnEnter' => True,
        'endConferenceOnExit' => True
  ));
return $response;
```

Then every time a new call comes directly hit this twiml.